# getting uncompressed CIImage data

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, core-image, ciimage

I'm trying to get `CIImage` uncompress data.
For now the only way I found to get **compressed** data is using `CIContext` as follow:

```
let ciContext = CIContext()

let ciImage = CIImage(color: .red).cropped(to: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 192, height: 192))

guard let ciImageData = ciContext.jpegRepresentation(of: ciImage, colorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!, options: [:]) else {
    fatalError()
}

print(ciImageData.count) // Prints 1331
```

Is it possible to get (as efficiently as possible) the uncompressed `CIImage` data?

Comment: Are you aware that JPEG is a format for *compressing* image data?

Comment: Hey @MartinR, thank you for responding! Yes, but when taking a regular .jpg image, I can calculate the raw data (WidthxHeightxChannelsx4). But when creating the CIIMage I'm not getting the same values, or at least calculate it up to  442368

Comment: "WidthxHeightxChannelsx4" is not the raw data. That's how many bytes it would take if you were to store the image in another format that does not do compression, not jpeg. The raw jpeg data ***is*** 1331 bytes.

Comment: `ciImageData.count` is the size of the JPEG compressed image. The very purpose of the image compression is to use less bytes than the raw image size.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for clarifying it. Makes sense. Is it possible to get the raw data (not compressed) of a CIImage? I'm trying to feed an ML model that expected a 192x192 (RGB), and when trying to feed it with this `CIImage it says Provided data count 1379 must match the required count 442368.`

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for clarifying it. Makes sense. Is it possible to get the raw data (not compressed) of a CIImage? I'm trying to feed an ML model that expected a 192x192 (RGB), and when trying to feed it with this CIImage it says Provided data count 1379 must match the required count 442368.

Comment: It seems like we finally got to the X of this XY problem. You should edit your question.

Comment: @Sweeper Doing it as we speak :)

Comment: I do not have much experience with CIImage (and even less with ML). But have you tried `ciImage.extent.size` ?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but it's returning the CIImage dimensional size. So for our case, it'll return 192,192

Comment: I would suggest that you update your question with a  [mcve] demonstrating the actual problem,  *including* the ML model generation.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, Martin! I'll try to make it as descriptive as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, `ciContext.jpegRepresentation` is compressing the image data as JPEG and gives you a `Data` object that can be written as-is as a JPEG file to disk (including image metadata).

You need to use a different `CIContext` API for rendering directly into (uncompressed) bitmap data:

```
let rowBytes = 4 * Int(ciImage.extent.width) // 4 channels (RGBA) of 8-bit data
let dataSize = rowBytes * Int(ciImage.extent.height)
var data = Data(count: dataSize)
data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { data in
    ciContext.render(ciImage, toBitmap: data, rowBytes: rowBytes, bounds: ciImage.extent, format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!)
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a `CVPixelBuffer` with the correct size and format and render into that with `CIContext.render(_ image: CIImage, to buffer: CVPixelBuffer)`. I think Core ML has direct support for `CVPixelBuffer` inputs, so this might be the better option.

Comment: Hey Frank! Best feeling in the world getting an answer from you haha :) Running your code results in a crash: `Thread 28: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7000086c5597)`

Comment: Also, I switched Skype address and I wanted to do a collab between our companies again :) add me again: admin@socialkit.com

Comment: Roi, I forgot the `withUnsafeMutableBytes` call. I updated my answer. It works for me in a playground now.

Comment: Awesome! Works :) Question: which is faster, using this method, or create CGImage with CIContext, and than access the underlying data of the CGImage?

Comment: They will probably have the same performance, but the "render to bitmap" method is precisely what you want. Core Graphics might add some overhead for metadata, compatibility, etc.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Also, when you have a sec ping me over Skype. A lot to catch up! ( admin@socialkit.com new Skype)